# Get value of row by index of the result MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying update/insert value of row based on the result i got from sorted query, find an element by index and then change it.

I am looking for a way of indexing the results but i can not find anything.

Here is what i got:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*)>= 3 
       THEN Answers.answer_id 
       ELSE COUNT(*) END 
FROM Answers 
WHERE Answers.question_id = 12 
ORDER BY Answers.answer_id ASC
```

I would like count to stop when it finds the value which meet requirement or assign the value of the index.

Table number 1 which is called Questions has 2 values:

```
uint8 - question_id
string - question
```

Table number 2 which is called Answers has 3 values:

```
uint8 - answer_id
string - answer
uint8 - question_id
```

I need to check order of given answer and change it's value.

For example using this query:

```
SELECT Answers.answer_id 
FROM Answers 
WHERE Answers.question_id = 12 
ORDER BY Answers.answer_id ASC
```

The response is (which are the answer_id's):

```
34  (index would be 0)
35  (index would be 1)
36  (index would be 2)
37  (index would be 3)
38  (index would be 4)
39  (index would be 5)
```

Instead of those id's i need indexes or stop counting when count achieves wanted number and then update the value if the index exists.

Comment: So you want only records that meet a certain criteria? And can you not use the primary key for the table as the unique index? Or perhaps I don't understand the desired result. Can you provide sample data?

Comment: Yes @kchason, i don't want to use unique id but to sort and check if the index of the element exist, then update or insert new element by appending.

Comment: do you mean a database index? or are you making up some numbering scheme and calling that an index?

Comment: @Randy i thought there would be an index to the rows as they are the response from sql server. So it could be used for checking if given index exist and then replace it's element string using update.

Comment: @Mac I think that is not an index in database terms.  in order to do an update, you need some key (one or more columns to form something unique generally) - then you can update those rows specified in that way.  it is generally also bad form to store derived values such as the index values you are describing.  use SQL to create them for the response, but do not store them.

Comment: @Randy yes, i know about the key. Thing is i need to compare the index with what i got by that change the elements from response with that "index" by pointing to this element using index or just by stopping at this element.